# Некорректное отображение в ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Если включить `listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;` то получается вот такой результат. Как сделать так чтобы  имя файла не выходило за рамки столбца?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штука в том, что в режиме `SmallIcon` *нет столбцов*. В нем на самом деле файлы идут слева направо и сверху вниз. Так что то, что вам кажется нарушением границ столбца, таковым не является. Единственный режим `ListView`, который имеет столбцы -- это `Details`.

Если вы все же хотите оставить именно режим `SmallIcon`, можно попробовать что-то из следующего:

1. Обрезать имена слишком длинных файлов при добавлении в контрол.

   ```
   int maxLength = 10; // или любое другое подходящее значение

   var item = listView.Items.Add("very loooooooooong text");
   if (item.Text.Length > maxLength)
   {
       item.Text = item.Text.Remove(maxLength - 3) + "...";
   }
   else
   {
       item.Text = item.Text.PadRight(maxLength);
   }
   ```
2. Использовать компонент [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), который поддерживает
   колонки во всех режимах.